Handling pre-release/development/local version of python packages w.r.t PEP440
I have a mono-repo where I have 2 python packages PackageA, PackageB where PackageB depends on PackageA~=1.0.1 (1.0.1 is the latest published version of PackageA)
When I develop in this mono-repo, I install these 2 packages in editable mode in a virtual environment, and as part of this install, a local version gets generated for each of these packages.
There are 2 requirements for these generated versions, to ensure pip can properly resolve dependencies:

a generated version should always be greater than or equal to latest published version.
a generated version should be less than next version to be published.

So for instance, given that I'm working in a branch called feature/foo, the version generated for PackageA would become: 1.0.1post+feature.foo
This version satisfies requirement 1 above. This can be confirmed by running:
python -c "from compatibleversion import check_version; assert check_version('1.0.1post+feature.foo', '>=1.0.1')"

It also satifies requirement 2 above:
python -c "from compatibleversion import check_version; assert check_version('1.0.1post+feature.foo', '<1.0.2')"

The problem starts with when I push PackageA with this version to a feed. Given that the following versions of PackageA exist in my feed:
1.0.1post+feature.foo

1.0.1

when I say pip install PackageA==1.0.1, pip installs 1.0.1post+feature.foo version of PackageA instead, which might potentially be a buggy version of PackageA, which at the same time fulfills the requirement ~=1.0.1
So my question is, how to make sure development versions of a package does not unintendedly get installed by pip, and at the same time fullfils the abovementioned two requirements.
PS. I have tried to find an answer to this question by reading https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/version-specifiers/#handling-of-pre-releases without luck, and as a workaround, have made a special feed (have called it test feed) for these development versions, and ensured that for production environments, pip do not have access to those test feeds.

If you don't want the post+... and since that's a post-release, you would want pip install PackageB<=1.0.1 wouldn't you?

Moreover, the usage of "post release" is documented is typically "to address minor errors in a final release that do not affect the distributed software", so essentially it should be identical to 1.0.1 in your example. If you want to push development release that may be buggy then you should be using those identifiers instead.

Let say I take your suggestion and want to push development releases that may be buggy and use for instance pre-release identifier, then one of the abovementioned requirements would not be met:
from compatibleversion import check_version
check_version('1.0.1dev1', '>=1.0.1') or check_version('1.0.1dev1', '~=1.0.1') -> returns False while True is expected
check_version('1.0.1dev1', '<1.0.2') -> this returns True as expected

Seems like this is a bug in compatibleversion python package. I tried with python's built-in methods and it works as expected: python -c "from packaging.version import Version; dev_version = Version('1.0.2.dev1'); last_published_version = Version('1.0.1'); next_version_to_be_published = Version('1.0.2'); assert dev_version>=last_published_version; assert dev_version<next_version_to_be_published"
